# Bootstrap 4 tabs without anchor (href) tag

Tags: jquery

How to create bootstrap 4 tabs without anchor (href) tag? I tried using `data-target` but no luck.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/5Lha68m1/3/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="createNewTemplate" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="available-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#available" role="tab" aria-controls="available" aria-selected="true">Available</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="new-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#new" role="tab" aria-controls="new" aria-selected="false">New</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="newTemplateContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="available" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="available-tab">Available content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="new" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="new-tab">
      New content...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally it should work with `data-target`.
> You can check out example 2 for this.

You can give the href property only the "`#`" and element ID to "`data-target`".

**Example**

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="createNewTemplate" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="available-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" data-target="#available" role="tab" aria-controls="available" aria-selected="true">Available</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="new-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" data-target="#new" role="tab" aria-controls="new" aria-selected="false">New</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="newTemplateContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="available" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="available-tab">Available content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="new" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="new-tab">
      New content...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Without `<a>` element.**

**Example**

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="createNewTemplate" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link cursor-pointer" id="available-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#available" role="tab" aria-controls="available" aria-selected="true">Available</div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link cursor-pointer active" id="new-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#new" role="tab" aria-controls="new" aria-selected="false">New</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="newTemplateContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="available" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="available-tab">Available content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="new" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="new-tab">
      New content...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```